# JOIN to get items without value in other table gives multiple results

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables like this:

**Table1**

| ObjectName | ObjectId | Status |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Name 1 | 001 | OK |
| Name 2 | 002 | OK |
| Name 3 | 003 | Wait |
| Name 4 | 004 | Wait |

**Table2**

| ObjectId | ObjectColor |
| --- | --- |
| 001 | Red |
| 001 | Blue |
| 002 | Magenta |
| 002 | Cyan |
| 003 | Blue |
| 003 | Green |
| 004 | Orange |
| 004 | Cyan |

Now, I want to query ObjectName of any item with status OK in Table1 and *without* the color blue in Table2.

The nearest I can come is this:

```sql
SELECT
   Table1.ObjectName
FROM
   Table1
   LEFT JOIN Table2 ON Table2.ObjectId = Table1.ObjectId
WHERE
   Table1.Status = 'OK'
   AND Table2.ObjectColor <> 'Blue'
```

This results in:

| ObjectName |
| --- |
| Name 1 |
| Name 2 |
| Name 2 |

I understand why this doesn't work. But what would be the correct approach?

I expect to only get one instance of **Name 2** from this query.

Thanks!

Comment: Which dbms you are using? Please tag that one.

Comment: Sorry, I was sure I had added it. It's there now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why join at all? You want data from table1, so select from table1. You want to exclude certain rows, which is why you have a `WHERE` clause. One restriction is Status = 'OK', the other is that `NOT EXISTS` 'Blue' for the object in table2.

```
select objectname
from table1
where status = 'OK'
and not exists
(
  select null
  from table2
  where table2.objectid = table1.objectid
  and table2.objectcolor = 'Blue'
);
```

As there are no nulls involved, you can do the same with the simpler `NOT IN`:

```
select objectname
from table1
where status = 'OK'
and objectid not in (select objectid from table2 where objectcolor = 'Blue');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use distinct if you just want the unique **ObjectName**

```
    SELECT
      Table1.ObjectName
FROM
   Table1
   
WHERE
   Table1.Status = 'OK'
   and not exists 
   (select 1 from Table2 where ObjectColor = 'Blue' and table2.objectid=table1.objectid)
```

Comment: Thanks. This still includes "Name 1" in the results, though.

Comment: You want only names with multiple items?

Comment: Sorry @Alex. Misread your question. I have changed my answer.

Comment: Thanks again. This query includes any results that have "Blue" and two or more other colors. I want to get just the name of any Object without the color blue.

Comment: I have again changed my answer. It will now return those objectname from table1 which have status ok and are not in table2 for objectcolor blue.

Comment: I think this will be the most efficient way to achieve your desired output.

Comment: @Alex Please let me know whether it's working for you or not.

Comment: It looks to now be the same solution as @Thorsten suggested, so it should work fine. Thanks again for the support.

Comment: Didn't notice that. Was working on the problem as you were having problem. Sorry for the delay. Couldn't understand it properly first time.

Answer (score 0):

```
 SELECT
     Table1.ObjectName
  FROM
  Table1
  JOIN
  (
     SELECT ObjectId FROM TABLE2 WHERE ObjectColor<>'BLUE'
  )X ON Table1.ObjectId=X.OBJECTID
 WHERE    Table1.Status = 'OK'
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query
At first I have selected the IDs from Table2 whose not have any entry belong to BLUE (SubQuery). After that I just join this result with Table1

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 
Inner Join
(
SELECT Objectid from Table2
group By Objectid
Having SUM(Case when ObjectColor ='Blue' Then 1 else 0 end)=0
) t2

on Table1.Objectid=t2.Objectid
And Table1.status='OK'
```